# Changing JSON array to to a pojo object array

Tags: java, android, gson

I am getting API response on the following format. I am working on Android project

```
    {
               Course: [
                  {
                    "Year": 2017,
                    "CourseTitle": "..",
                    "Quarter": "autumn",
                    },
                 {
                     "Year": 2017,
                    "CourseTitle": "..",
                    "Quarter": "autumn",
                 }

                ],

                Instructor: {

                 "name": ,
                 "address": 
                }  
   }
```

My goal is to get Course array of courses, and assign it to the POJO (plain old java object) that I created using [online tool](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/). I am also using the GSON library. I did find different implementation online, and I finally used this, and I was able to filter the nested object "Courses", which holds an array object of courses.

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject element = (JsonObject)parser.parse(response);
JsonElement responseWrapper = element.getAsJsonArray("Courses");
```

When I look responseWrapper using debugger tool, it holds a JSON array of course (objects). I wanted to assign these data to the "Course" POJO class I created

public class Course implements Parcelable {

```
private String href;
private int year;
private String courseTitle;
private String quarter;
private String courseTitleLong;
private String curriculumAbbreviation;
private String courseNumber;
```

}

I added the following line.

```
Course[] courseList = gson.fromJson(responseWrapper,Course[].class);
```

CourseList is an array of Course object, but when I look what I got using debugger tool all the field variables are "null". How could I solve this problem? Is there a better way I should have approached? The whole purpose is getting array of course objects so I could manipulate it for display.

Comment: Problem solved. My issue was I am using auto generated pojo class. If you look the member variables the name does not match with the one I am getting from api. For example, on the API the key is "CourseTitle", and in my pojo class I have it as "courseTitle". This is true for all the member variables. Yesterday, took me an hour or so finally slept and I woke up in the morning and I see the problem. Lesson I learned is If you stuck on things just leave it aside or take a break.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename your fields to exactly match the json response, even case-wise.

Comment: Thanks for the initial response, but you edited your response. Now, you wrote the same thing I said on my comment. May be you didn't look at it. Your initial response was to use List<Course>

Comment: Oh okay! Yeah if you noticed I added 3 possibilities after my edit. 1) The list 2) Creating an object with a list and the 3rd was the naming of the fields. I changed it again after trying the first 2 and realizing it makes no difference. Goodluck!